# Mysql Insert, Inserção automática?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$insert = mysql_query ( "INSERT INTO analise VALUES ( $analise_hora )" ) ;
```

Estou tentando inserir esse dado com essa função automaticamente quando o usuário entrar na página, mas não esta sendo inserido, a minha variável da hora esta certa dei um echo pra testar, minha conexão com o banco de dados esta ok.

Não era pra enviar automático só com esse `insert` ?

Comment: Qual é o erro que aparece?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você tem mais de um campo nessa tabela, o erro acontece se não estiver definido em qual campo você quer inserir.

```
INSERT INTO analise (nome_campo) VALUES ( $analise_hora )
```

Comment: Era esse o erro, Thanks.